# How do I interface with my WinForms application from a UnitTest

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

I have built a WinForms application which consists of just a RichTextBox and ive built it into an EXE.

The purpose of this EXE is to act as a logger so that when im running tests the log is output onto this EXE.

Important note is that this EXE is referenced in a separate Unit Test (to be run  by Microsoft Test Manager) solution by adding the EXE as a reference in the project. This seems to expose the objects I need.

I've had some success using HTTP through the ChannelFactory interfaces, but i'd prefer to talk to the EXE directly.

These unit tests I have are essentially sending and receiving data from OpenVMS, and some of these tests can take some time to complete.

So I built a new Console project to test the public methods I've exposed in my logger.exe and so far heres my code:

```
TerminalLogger.Logger term = new TerminalLogger.Logger();
term.TerminalLog("Test");
```

When I run this the form opens, but nothing loads in. So im assuming thats because the form runs on the same thread? Do I need to have this form running on its own thread?

I notice that if I add "term" to watch in Visual Studio and inspect the richtextbox I can see that it has actually written the value "Test" to the object, but of course I cannot see this as the form hasnt fully rendered in.

I still need to be able to call methods like term.LogMessage("Example Message") and get it to display on the form.

If you need extra info please add a comment and i'll do my best to elaborate more on my question.

Comment: This is not a unit test at all, more some kind of integration test.

Comment: What I mean is the project type is a Unit test. It then runs on a VM via Microsoft Test Manager

Comment: But im assuming if I can get it working through a console app then I can get it working through a Unit Test type.

Comment: I assume TerminalLogger.Logger is a System.Windows.Form.  If so, simply instantiating that Form will not make it appear on the screen.  You must start an STAThread and have it run a Windows Event loop.  This is difficult and requires some low-level understanding of Windows event loops and how WinForms works.  It is probably easier to run the .EXE and communicate with it indirectly, unless you absolutely need it to be in process.

Comment: It is indeed a System.Windows.Form. Is there an alternative type I could make? Maybe a WPF?

Comment: You don't usually use unit tests when you have a GUI involved.  Instead you'd unit test methods in classes that are separated from the GUI components.  Integration or GUI Testing usually handles the actual testing of the gui and event handling.

Comment: Please read the question. I explained I use unit tests for Microsoft test manager, namely using SpecFlow to generate the "unit tests". The unit test framework is often used when testing GUI, for example when using selenium, specflow etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well I asked one of the web developers at my organisation on the offchance they might be able to help, and apparently calling a redraw fixed my issue!.

I simply added:

```
        LogConsole.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (this.Visible)
            {
                this.Refresh();
            }
        };
```

Here is how I call the code from my unit test:

```
TerminalLogger.Logger term = new TerminalLogger.Logger();

        term.Show();
        term.TerminalLog("Test1");
        term.TerminalLog("Test2");
```

And I can send messages to it without it locking up.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution in that although the form repaints itself it becomes "locked" so you cant scroll up and down the log.